# Передача данных в POST

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, возможно ли в POST массив передать данные из списка ul/ol?

Answer (score 1):

Можно, и не одним способом. Сконструировать строку с параметрами запроса, или передать массив целиком, или по сабмиту сгенерить хидены с нужными значениями, все в твоих руках. Потребуется js.

Answer (score 0):

Список же не селектовый, так что можешь через в jquery получить массив данных и через json передать.